# Cursor package won't get removed

Tags: package-management, cursor

I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon. I went on a PPA-adding binge (I know... I know) and downloaded a bunch of themes, icons, and cursors. Problem is one of the many packages I downloaded is broken somehow! The package is `mbuntu-y-icons-v4` from `ppa:noobslab/themes`.

Here's what it says when I do `sudo apt-get install mbuntu-y-icons-v4`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mbuntu-y-icons-v4 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 12.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu/ trusty/main mbuntu-y-icons-v4 all 3.12.2~trusty~NoobsLab.com [12.3 MB]
Fetched 12.3 MB in 35s (347 kB/s)                        
dpkg: error processing package mbuntu-y-icons-v4 (--configure):
 package mbuntu-y-icons-v4 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mbuntu-y-icons-v4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Using `sudo apt-get remove` or `clean` or `autoremove` or `sudo apt-get install -f` does nothing either in terms of solving the problem.

Here's what it says when I do `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mbuntu-y-icons-v4`:

```
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'totem-mozilla' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 2508592 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mbuntu-y-icons-v4 (3.12.2~trusty~NoobsLab.com) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative (null) because link group x-cursor-theme is broken
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme to provide /etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme (x-cursor-theme) in auto mode
update-alternatives: error: unable to install `/etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme.dpkg-tmp' as `/etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mbuntu-y-icons-v4 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mbuntu-y-icons-v4
```

As you can see, one of the problems is that apparently the `x-cursor-theme` under `/etc/alternatives` is broken. So then I looked up how to resolve that, so I did the following:

```
sudo rm -i /etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme /etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme
CURSOR=DMZ-White
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "$CURSOR"
sudo update-alternatives --set x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/$CURSOR/cursor.theme
```

The last line gives me the following result:

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative     /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme because link group x-cursor-theme is broken
update-alternatives: error: unable to install `/etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme.dpkg-tmp' as `/etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme': No such file or directory
```

I just want to get rid of that stupid `mbuntu-y-icons-v4` package and make my cursor work normally again (it changes depending on the program it hovers over). I've spent 5 hours on this! Please help.

Comment: quick hack: edit (as root or with sudo) `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mbuntu-y-icons-v4.p*` and insert the line `exit 0` immediately after the `#!` line for each of the `{pre,post}{rm,inst}` scripts.  You should now be able to remove the package with dpkg, without it failing due to errors in one or more of those scripts.

Comment: @cas Thanks, that helped me remove the package... Problem is its "ghosts" still lurk! Whenever I open a PDF file for example, the old mouse still appears somehow... Whenever I do `sudo sudo update-alternatives --set x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/$CURSOR/cursor.theme` for example, it gives me `update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme': Too many levels of symbolic links` and basically I can't change the mouse! How can I solve this perpetually broken `x-cursor-theme`?

Comment: find out what `/etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme` is pointing to and follow the symlinks.  and why are you setting it to a filename  that includes the variable "$CURSOR"?  try `sudo update-alternatives x-cursor-theme` and pick one of the options offered.  Make sure that dmz-cursor-themes is installed properly - if necessary, use `sudo apt-get --reinstall install dmz-cursor-theme`